# Method to deserialize from Number jackson

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, deserialization

I received a Json with a long such as:

```
{
    "idMediaType": 11
}
```

I recevied a item to be added to the list. I have put a System.out.println to debug but it doesn¡t print anything. I use JPA and Jackson.

That's my code:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addItemList(MovieToAdd movieToAdd, @Context HttpServletRequest req,@PathParam("id") Long idList) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("debugging");
    Long loggedUserId = getLoggedUser(req);
    int t = listService.addItemToList(loggedUserId,idList,movieToAdd.idMediaType);
    if (t == 0) return  Response.ok().build();
    else return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
}


 public static class MovieToAdd {
    @NotNull public Long idMediaType;
}
```

I get that error:

```
{"type":"JSON processing error","message":"Can not construct instance of org.udg.pds.simpleapp_javaee.rest.LlistaRESTService$MovieToAdd: no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (111)"}
```

D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (224-byte body)

Comment: 1. Don't use public fields. 2. It seems that what you're actually receving is `111`, not `{"idMediaType": 11}`.

Comment: Can you specify the full package name of `@NotNull` ?

Comment: @JBNizet, that's the issue, `String input = "111"; MovieToAdd m = jsonMapper.readValue(input, MovieToAdd.class);` gives same exception